# Web page with high CPU usage -- how to profile

Tags: javascript, profiling, google-chrome-devtools

I have a webpage to optimize. When I enter it, the CPU usage increases drastically. I tried to use Chrome Dev Tools, but profiler 92% of the time is in the `(program)` line. What could I do to find the culprit of this behavior?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've had the same issues before. I don't have a lot of experience using Chrome Dev Tools but here are some useful links:

- [Debugging JavaScript - Chrome DevTools - Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging)
- [JavaScript Profiling With The Chrome Developer Tools | Smashing Coding](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/06/12/javascript-profiling-chrome-developer-tools/)
- [Chrome DevTools - Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-memory-profiling)

Answer (score 6):

Please use Timeline panel. It will show you what the page does.
It shows information about javascript calls, gc, layout, paint etc.

https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/timeline

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/evaluate-performance/reference is the new link